# Get Google Search Result with Java using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

first of all i search this problem in stackoverflow database and google. Unfortunately i couldn't find a solution.

I am trying to get Google Search Result for a keyword. Heres my code :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    Document doc;
    try{
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/search?as_q=&as_epq=%22Yorkshire+Capital%22+&as_oq=fraud+OR+allegations+OR+scam&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=lang_en&cr=countryCA&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=").userAgent("Mozilla").ignoreHttpErrors(true).timeout(0).get();
        Elements links = (Elements) doc.select("li[class=g]");
        for (Element link : links) {
            Elements titles = link.select("h3[class=r]");
            String title = titles.text();

            Elements bodies = link.select("span[class=st]");
            String body = bodies.text();

            System.out.println("Title: "+title);
            System.out.println("Body: "+body+"\n");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

And heres the errors : https://prnt.sc/ro4ooi

It says : can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.iterable ( at links )..

When i delete the (Elements) : https://prnt.sc/ro4pa9

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. Links can break; in fact the link doesn't work for me. Put everything here in the question instead. See [ask].

Comment: You shouldn't have to cast `doc.select` to `Elements` since that is what it returns - so maybe that's a clue.

Comment: Include the jsoup `implementation` statement from your app build.gradle and also list your import statements - and be sure to `Invalidate cache and restart` from main menu.  Your code produces no (compile) errors (or warnings) (other than the redundant cast) in my environment - and the cast is not required (redundant).